# PostgreSQL: array_append() create ARRAY if it doesn't already exist

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have an existing `users` table in my database (PostgreSQL 9.4.18) that I am modifying as such:

```
ALTER TABLE users
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS groups INT[];
```

So far so good.

I have a SQL statement that uses `array_append()` to add groups for my users:

```
// NOTE: this bit prevents duplicate entries and casts to integer value --> NOT (groups @> ARRAY[?]::INT[])

UPDATE users
SET groups = array_append(groups, ?)
WHERE NOT (groups @> ARRAY[?]::INT[])
  AND id = ?
```

This statement works fine -- but only if the selected user has `groups` defined as an array.

If the matched user has no `groups` array defined (null?), the statement just silently fails to do anything.

```
# SELECT id, groups FROM users WHERE id=11111;
  id   | groups
-------+-------
 11111 |
(1 row)
```

---

My question is:

How can I modify my SQL statement to create an empty array first if it doesn't already exist?

I've tried using functions like `COALESCE()` to inject an empty array as a default value without any luck... but I'm probably just not approaching this correctly.

Help?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()` to create an empty array to which you append the new value:

```
UPDATE users
  SET groups = array_append(coalesce(groups,'{}'), ?)
WHERE ? <> ALL (coalesce(groups, '{}'))
  AND id = ?
```

Note that `NOT (groups @> ARRAY[?]::INT[])` can be simplified (in my opinion) to `? <> all(groups)`

Comment: So, the `coalesce()` bit works to insert a proper INT[] without the WHERE clause. However, the WHERE clause (checking to see if the value exists in the array) is probably failing because `groups` is NULL

Comment: Yeah, this not going to work: `select null::int[] @> array[1]; NULL`.

Comment: @arthurakay: ah, right I did consider that. I have changed the WHERE clause